# Volume group disappeared, LVs still available

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, lvm, disk-volume

I've run into an issue with my KVM host which runs VMs on a LVM volume. As of last night the logical volumes are no longer seen as such (I can't create snapshots of them even though I have been for months now).

Running any scans all result in nothing being found:

```
[root@apollo ~]# pvscan
No matching physical volumes found

[root@apollo ~]# vgscan
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
No volume groups found

root@apollo ~]# lvscan
No volume groups found
```

If I try restoring the VG conf backup from `/etc/lvm/backups/vg0` I get the following error:

```
[root@apollo ~]# vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/backup/vg0 vg0
Couldn't find device with uuid 20zG25-H8MU-UQPf-u0hD-NftW-ngsC-mG63dt.
Cannot restore Volume Group vg0 with 1 PVs marked as missing.
Restore failed.
```

`/etc/lvm/backups/vg0` has the following for the physical volume:

```
physical_volumes {

            pv0 {
                    id = "20zG25-H8MU-UQPf-u0hD-NftW-ngsC-mG63dt"
                    device = "/dev/sda5"    # Hint only

                    status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                    flags = []
                    dev_size = 4292870143   # 1.99902 Terabytes
                    pe_start = 384
                    pe_count = 524031       # 1.99902 Terabytes
            }
}
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sda` shows the following:

```
[root@apollo ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 6000.1 GB, 6000069312512 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 5722112 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000188b7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               2       32768    33553408   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2           32769       33280      524288   83  Linux
/dev/sda3           33281     1081856  1073741824   83  Linux
/dev/sda4         1081857     3177984  2146435072   85  Linux extended
/dev/sda5         1081857     3177984  2146435071+  8e  Linux LVM
```

The server is running a 4 disk HW RAID10 which seems perfectly healthy according to megacli and smartd.

The only odd message in `/var/log/messages` is the following which shows up every couple of hours:

```
Jun 10 09:41:57 apollo udevd[527]: failed to create queue file: No space left on device
```

Output of `df -h`

```
[root@apollo ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3            1016G  119G  847G  13% /
/dev/sda2             508M   67M  416M  14% /boot
```

Does anyone have any ideas what to do next? The VMs are all running fine at the moment apart from not being able to snapshot them.

**Updated with extra info**
It's not a lack of inodes:

```
[root@apollo ~]# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda3            67108864   48066 67060798    1% /
/dev/sda2              32768      47   32721    1% /boot
```

pvs, vgs & lvs either output nothing or "No volume groups found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think somehow udev stopped working so you do not have access to the low-level commands.

You can try:

```
pvs
vgs
lvs
```

commands to check your running lvm configuration.

You can try restarting udev (or rebooting the server as a last resort).

Just out of curiosity what does `df -i` says?

Comment: I've updated my question with the output and will try restarting udev now.

Comment: ok, glad to help.